# Copying the first two values of an array into a new array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have sorted an array of objects into descending order based on one of their variables. I now need to take the first two values of this array and place them in a new `String` array. What I have so far is below, but Im obviously making a stupid mistake somewhere.

```
public String[] teamsToProgress()
{
    Arrays.sort(teams);
    String[] teamsToProgress = new String[2];
    for (int i=0; i<2 ; i++)
    {
        teams[i] = teamsToProgress[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this code even compile? I can't see how you would be able sort teams and then redeclare it.

Comment: Incorrect code aside, you wouldn't need a loop. If you're taking the first two values you could just use `teams[0]` and `teams[1]`. Easier to read and quicker to understand

Comment: @fdsa `Team[] teams;` is declared earlier on, that probably shouldn't be there. The compilation error I am getting is "incompatible types" for the 'i' in `teamsToProgress[i]`

Answer (score 0):

You try to assign `String` to a `Team` field (here: `teams[i] = teamsToProgress[i];`). You'll have to convert (**not** casting) the `String` to a `Team` instance before assigning.

Answer (score 0):

`teams[i] = teamsToProgress[i];` should be reversed, this make no sense. You're also missing a return statement.

```
public String[] teamsToProgress()
{
    Arrays.sort(teams);
    String[] teamsToProgress = new String[2];
    for (int i=0; i<2 ; i++)
    {
        teamsToProgress[i] = teams[i]; //.getSomething() ?
    }
    return teamsToProgress;
}
```

Comment: This is throwing a compilation error "incompatible types" for the "i" in `teams[i]`

Comment: Yes, as `teamsToProgress` is a `String` array and `teams` is a `Team` array. So I don't see why you would this anyway, perhaps you want to call some method on your team instance? If you could edit your post and describe why and what exactly you are trying to achieve it'd be easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

If your just looking for a logical error, here it is:

`teams[i] = teamsToProgress[i];` should be replaced to `teamsToProgress[i] = teams[i];`

I'm not getting into the details of the syntax involved. But I guess this is what you wanted based on your question.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear enough as we still need to learn about Team object structure. but I'm guessing you are looking after something like this.

```
public String[] teamsToProgress(Team[] teams) //pass your sorted teams array as a param.
 {
    String[] teamsToProgress = new String[2];
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
       teamsToProgress[i] = String.valueOf(teams[i]); //convert teams[i] to string
    }

    return teamsToProgress;// you need to return an array
 }
```